Add a value to filter result in Google Sheets
I have the following formula that works in Google Sheets
    =Sort({IFERROR((FILTER({'My Log'!B13:B, 'My Log'!F13:F, 'My Log'!E13:E, 'My Log'!H13:H, 'My Log'!I13:I,'My Log'!J13:J, 'My Log'!K13:K,'My Log'!L13:L, 'My Log'!P13:P, 'My Log'!R13:R}, 
'My Log'!O13:O = "Y", 
'My Log'!N13:N =B1
)), {"","","","","","","","","","",""})
},1, TRUE)

This fills the cells as I would like However I now need to add a value to each row that is outputted Googling I should be able to simply add a cell reference that contains the additional value and it would be added e.g. as below 'My Newvalue'!C1, however when I do that the output is lost.
So how can I add a column to the output with the Text held at 'My Newvalue'!C1 ?
Example Sheet here
=Sort({IFERROR((FILTER({'My Log'!B13:B, 'My Log'!F13:F, 'My Log'!E13:E, 'My Newvalue'!C1, 'My Log'!H13:H, 'My Log'!I13:I,'My Log'!J13:J, 'My Log'!K13:K,'My Log'!L13:L, 'My Log'!P13:P, 'My Log'!R13:R}, 
'My Log'!O13:O = "Y", 
'My Log'!N13:N =B1
)), {"","","","","","","","","","",""})
},1, TRUE)


Would help to see a minimal, reproducible example with some faux data. The way you've added 'My Newvalue'!C1, is as a filter criteria, not adding it to the output.

Example sheet added thanks


Replace this in your second test formula
'My Newvalue'!C1

with
let(Σ,'My Newvalue'!C1,wrapcols(Σ,rows('My Log'!A13:A),Σ))


Wow, thanks it works, but what is Σ and what is it doing, I just want to try to understand it.

its just an identifier I assigned for 'My Newvalue'!C1; you can use something different & of your choice within the let function
